# Extracting logon/logoff events using powershell

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-winevent

I need to extract a list of local logons/logoffs from a Windows 7 workstation. I've got a saved copy of the security event log in evtx format, and I'm having a few issues.

The following powershell extracts all events with ID `4624` or `4634`:

```
Get-WinEvent -Path 'C:\path\to\securitylog.evtx' | where {$_.Id -eq 4624 -or $_.Id -eq 4634}
```

I want to then filter for only `logon type = 2 (local logon)`. Piping this to:

```
 | where {$_.properties[8].value -eq 2}
```

However seems to drop all the `id=4634` (logoff) events.

Even for the event `id = 4624` events, there is no userid present. Eg piping to:

```
 | select-object -property Timecreated,TaskDisplayName,MachineName,userid
```

or otherwise piping to `Export-Csv`, the `userid` is blank.

Two issues are:

1. Why are events with id 4634 drops when piped to where `{$_.properties[8].value -eq 2}` ?
2. Why is `userid` empty? How can I get the `userid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Notice that 8 is not a magic number. It's the 9th property (index starting from 0) in the XML defined by the 4624 event. You can see it in the event viewer, if you open the Details tab and switch to XML view. When looking at the 4634 event, you can see that the Logon Type property is now the 5th - so you may want to modify your query to something like:

   where {{$*.Id -eq 4624 -and $*.properties[8] -eq 2} -or {$*.Id -eq 4634 -and $*.properties[4] -eq 2}}
2. userid is just not defined for these events. You might want to look at the TargetUserName property defined in the XML (the 6th property).

Comment: Thanks for that - this command works to extract the events:

Get-WinEvent -Path 'C:\path\to\securitylog.evtx' | where {($_.Id -eq 4624 -and $_.properties[8].value -eq 2) -or ($_.Id -eq 4634 -and $_.properties[4].value -eq 2) }

Is there a way to refer to the properties elements by the XML element names?

Also, how do I actually print out the values of the property arrays? Select-object allows me to print properties (eg select-object -property TTimecreated,TaskDisplayName,MachineName ) but I can't seem to figure out how to print a specific element from the properties array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I ended up going with. It prints out comma separated values:

```
$evts = Get-WinEvent -Path 'C:\path\to\securitylog.evtx' | where {($_.Id -eq 4624 -and $_.properties[8].value -eq 2) -or ($_.Id -eq 4634 -and $_.properties[4].value -eq 2) }
foreach ($e in $evts)
{
    # get the attributes
    $ds = $e.TimeCreated
    $tdn = $e.TaskDisplayName
    $mn = $e.MachineName

    # userid will vary depending on event type:
    if($e.Id -eq 4624) { $userid = $e.properties[5].value }
    if($e.Id -eq 4634) { $userid = $e.properties[1].value }

    write-host ("{0},{1},{2},{3}" -f [string]$ds,[string]$tdn,[string]$mn,[string]$userid)
}
```